# F# How to add first 2 nr. in infinite seqence, then add next 2?

Tags: f#

Example input: {1;2;3;4...}

1. How to take first 2 numbers & and add them ?
2. Put result into new sequence
3. Then take next 2 numbers & add them
4. Put result into new sequence
5. etc..

```
let nat = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 1)
```

Result should be: {3; 7...}

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
let nat = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 1)
let f (s:seq<int>) =
    Seq.chunkBySize 2 s
    |> Seq.map Seq.sum
f nat // seq [3; 7; 11; 15; ...]
```

Comment: You can also use an inline function to support all number types instead of just int: `let inline f s = ...`

Comment: @Arshia001 what other number types? reals are not enumerable.

Comment: Unsigned ints, for example?